# android listview attribute

Tags: android

Is listview has any attribute (e.g. productId, like hidden field of html form) can be set for later use? The following is to build a listview by using an array

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, catlist);
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The listview will display the text inside of the catlist, i want to pass the productid which corresponding the category text to another activity when users click on every item.

Answer (score 0):

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListner()) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

You will have two arrays `catlist` and `catIds`, `catlist` will have name to show in ListView and `catIds` will have ids at same indices, now when the user click any item, you will get its position and grab the id from `catIds` at that position like this:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> pr, View v, int position, long id) {
      String id = catIds.get(position);
      //use this id for any purpose.
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, you understand what i asking. but another problem arise.
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> pr, View v, int position, long id) {      
        System.out.println("abc");
      }
  });

i wrote this code for testing, but nothing output, why?